# How to know if Emacs is running in batch mode

Tags: batch-mode

I have one file that needs to behave differently depending on whether Emacs is running in batch mode (non interactive) or normal mode.

```el
(if batch-mode-t 
    a-func
  b-func)
```

How can I detect this?

Comment: See [this S.O. thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194197/how-can-i-detect-whether-emacs-is-running-in-batch-mode).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can look at the variable `noninteractive`, for example:

```
(if noninteractive
    a
  b)
```